# Checkbox checked and inserted into database

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to save the data into the database based on the checkbox. If the checkbox is checked then save, else don't save. My idea is passing the ng-model value to php value then do validation but it doesn't work.

```
blade.php

<input type="checkbox" name="update_info" ng-model="item.update_info"></label>
```

php

```
$value = "{{item.update_info}}"

if ($vendor === NULL && $value === true) {
            try {
                    DB::table('vendors')
                        ->insert([
                        'vendor_id' => $vendor_id,
                        'price' => $price
                        ]);
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    throw new TransactionException([$e->getMessage()]);
                }

        }
```

Comment: What do you get when you echo `$value`?

Comment: whats this syntax error doing here `$value = "{{item.update_info}}"` no `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a checkbox is not a boolean type true, but a string with value 'on';

Try this:

```
if ($vendor === NULL && $value === 'on') {
```

Answer (score 0):

You use value in checkbox when it is checked the value will go to the server, for eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="update_info" ng-model="item.update_info" value="1"></label>
```

So you can validate in the server

```
$value = Input::get('update_info');
if($value){ ... }
```

Try this and let me know how it works :)